# The Software infrastructure Requirements for building a provider hosted app for my on-premise sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, administration, installation, app

I want to build my first provider hosted app for my on-premise sharepoint 2013 enterprise server.
now as i know when using a provider hosted app, i need to create a remote IIS application to deploy the provider hosted App.

now since we are using an on-premise sharepoint 2013, and we have 2 servers for the sharepoint farm (application server + DB server). so my question can i create the new IIS web application to be inside the current sharepoint application server? which is windows 2008 R2 ? i mean i can open the IIS manager inside my current sharepoint application server and create a new web application under IIS, and use this new web application to build my provider hosted App, is this valid ? Or if i want to build a provider hosted app , then the remote IIS web application must be on another server and can not be inside the DB or sharepoint application server ?? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

While you can build the app on the same server, but it won't make any sense since the purpose of provider hosted add-in is to separate your code from the SharePoint environment. You can do it for testing, etc.. but it's not recommended for a production environment.

Comment: now if you put your self in the hat of the customer , so they will find it too much to ask for a separate server to host apps (they will say that on previous versions we don't do this, and i can understand them, and when i mentioned this the first question was raised if can we install them on the same SP server or not !!).. second point having the provider hosted app on the same sharepoint server does not mean we will break the whole benefits of having provider hosted app..

Comment: as still the app code will run outside the sharepoint processes . same as having the search service running on the same application server,, now you might face a timeout of the search,, but still your site collections runs correctly ..

Comment: Yes, but it's still Microsoft's code that's running on the same box, whatever happens when you need to upgrade to a newer version or anything, it will be supported by the next version of SharePoint, as it's their native code. That's why they recommend in the first place to host SharePoint on a server that's not used by other applications

Comment: can you please explain your last comment in more details please? what is the relation between upgrading sharepoint and having the  app on the same server as sharepoint ? can you explain this in more details please?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons, for instance, hosting websites on the same server as the SharePoint server would require you to use application pools, there's a threshhold for number of application pools per server (I guess it's 20 app pool per server), if you exceed that, you won't be supported anymore by Microsoft. So it's not the best idea to use IIS in SharePoint server to host other applications

Comment: i am not saying it is the best idea to have the apps on the same server as sharepoint,what i am saying is that it is an additional cost to host apps on new server. specifically at the beginning we might only need 3-4 apps. so it will not be feasible to have a separate server for these 4 apps.. i am talking from the customer point of view , not froma pure technical point of view.. i might start have the first set of apps on the same SP server, and as the number of Apps grow we can ask our customers to pay for additional server.. specifically when the SharePoint performance is affected

Comment: Yes, and as I said in my answer, "you can build the app on the same server" but it's not recommended.

Comment: i know it is not recommended , but what is the main reason of not doing so other than performance ? you mentioned a problem when upgrading sharepoint , but i did not get this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50032/discussion-between-mohamed-derhalli-and-john-g).